# file_get_contents('php://input') doesn't work with Bash pipe

Tags: php, bash

I was working on my project and suddenly stdin in PHP stops working.

I have code in PHP:

*test.php*

```php
<?php

$stdin = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo ">>>>>";
echo $stdin;
echo "<<<<<";
```

and I'm executing it with:

```
echo 'HELLO' | php -f test.php
>>>>><<<<<
```

This works fine:

```
echo 'HELLO' | php -c "echo file_get_contents('php://input');"
HELLO
```

and it doesn't work, I'm spending way too much time on this. Why this simple code doesn't work? Any clues? I'm using Fedora GNU/Linux with php 7.4.19.

Comment: Have a look at `echo 'HELLO' | php -c "blah"`. Your command line switch is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: `-c` isn't "run this code", `-r` is. Your second example is equivalent to `echo 'HELLO' | php` where PHP will interpret stdin as a script to be executed. Since there are no tags or code, it's passed as-is to stdout. `echo 'HELLO' | php -r "echo '>>'; echo file_get_contents('php://input'); echo '<<';"` is equivalently broken as the first snippet, and 0stone0's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last example uses the `-c` parameter, from the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/php):

> `-c`
>
> Look for php.ini file in the directory path or use the specified file

I guess you ment to use `-r`:

> `-r`
>
> Run PHP code without using script tags `'<?..?>'`

In your answer, the `HELLO` comes from the shell, if you replace `-c` with `-r` is **shows nothing**, for that, please continue reading

<sub>The above seen in shell, on my local machine, in a snippet because the answer is getting way to long</sub>

```js
$
$ echo 'HELLO' | php -c "echo 'Test'; echo file_get_contents('php://input');"
HELLO
$
$ # HELLO Comes from shell, no 'echo 'Test';
$
$ echo 'HELLO' | php -r "echo 'Test'; echo file_get_contents('php://input');"
Test%
$
$ # With `-r` only the Test echo, because php:// input is empty
$
$
$ echo 'HELLO' | php -r "echo 'Test'; echo file_get_contents('php://stdin');"
TestHELLO
$
$ # If we use php://stdin we get both the echo's
$
```

---

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data **from the request body**

Your data is in `stdin`, so you'll need [`file_get_contents('php://stdin')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> `php://stdin`, `php://stdout` and `php://stderr` allow direct access to the corresponding input or output stream of the PHP process.

<sup>[Source of above quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)</sup>

---

```php
<?php

$stdin = file_get_contents('php://stdin');

echo ">>>>>";
echo $stdin;
echo "<<<<<";
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6W4JCUzT8FWIS0zJzU@PbUkPjk/ryQ1r6RYQx2owEpfH6xAXdOaiys1OSNfQckOBJSsITyIdihHyQYElKz///dw9fHxBwA)

---

Another option is to use [`stream_get_contents(STDIN)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php):

```php
<?php

$stdin = stream_get_contents(STDIN);

print(">>>>>");
print($stdin);
print("<<<<<");
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6W4JCUzT8FWobikKDUxNz49tSQ@OT@vJDWvpFgjOMTF00/TmouroCgzr0RDyQ4ElIACED5EL5yrZAMCIGkU8P@/h6uPjz8A)

Comment: I mean it works, but I'm still curious why the original behaviour is happening.

Comment: Please see my edit @Sammitch.

Comment: lol never mind, `-c` isn't a valid argument, and STDIN is treated as a PHP file and passed through unchanged since there are no tags or code.

Comment: Just looking at the `man` page ;) `-c` is for: `Look for php.ini file in this directory`